# Paypal SDK Integration with Android Login Failed

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have been trying to integrate Paypal SDK with Android for payment testing using SANDBOX API CREDENTIALS. However, my issue is that whenever I try to login, it always shows Login Failed. System error. Please try again later.

How do I resolve this issue? Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using the long deprecated and now end of life Mobile SDK.

Use the new [Native Checkout SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/) instead.